# How to iteratively access data in data frames in r?

Tags: r

I follow the step in this post: [Is there a way to define a subsequent set of data.frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652050/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-subsequent-set-of-data-frame-in-r) to assign data to a whole set of data frames.

What I did is to store all my "symbol" into a vector x <- c("A","B",C"...), then use the above method to get a set of data.frame such as A, B, C...etc.

My question is: how can I access these data.frame iteratively by another for loop, then assign to vectors such as:

```
x <- c("A","B","C") ## A, B, C are names of data.frame
y <- c("a","b","c") ## a, b, c are names of vectors
for (i in x){ y[i] <- x[i][,2]}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You should have definitely followed the solutions proposed without the `assign` and not the one you have accepted. You should have created a `list` of data.frames instead of different objects. Accessing to element of a list is very simple and clean; accessing to objects in an environment maybe difficult and dirty. For instance, if `x` were a list of your data.frames, a simple `x[[i]][,2]` would have worked. I'm not going to say how you could do what you asked, since I think is much more "instructive" to reproduce your objects as a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nicola! Let me try to that approach first!